# open a new tab using jquery triggerd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link on a public view of a site that is only allowed to be followed if the user is authenticated.  So right now if an anonymous user clicks the link then a log-in modal will popup.  I store an ID of which link was clicked and send with the login credentials.  Then the page refreshes and in `$(document).ready()` I do a

```
$('selectedLink').trigger('click');
```

I have found problems with triggering a click and expecting it to follow the `href` attribute.  So I now have a `onclick` attribute that is firing fine.  In the `onclick` attribute I have a line that says `window.open(url)`

It is firing fine , but always blocked by the browsers pop-up blocker.  Is there any way to trigger a click in script and let it open a new tab??

Comment: window.open(url) opens a new tab for me...what browser are you having issues with?

Comment: @tymeJV see http://jsfiddle.net/vyW3V/1/ , see how you get "Pop-Up Blocked"

Comment: On the page load I do...when I actually click the button it all works fine. (Im using IE9) Nvm, I just realized what you're trying to... /facepalm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening tabs try to do nothing process intensive (that may cause a delay) after the click.

The click is like a permission from the user to open a new tab, if you take too long before using that permission, browsers may find it suspicious & classify it as a popup.

If you could share the tab open / redirect function...

Comment: I have window.open() after an ajax call , Im going to try ot move it to before the ajax

Comment: I will , the browser allows the local host to make the pop-up happen , so i have to publish to beta site to actually test

Comment: I doubt moving it up would suffice. You could rather put it as a direct call. The window in your fiddle actually gets blocked in IE. Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/vyW3V/5/

Comment: thats still getting blocked in Chrome - and ideally i'd like to track the click , so the function is preferred

Comment: You could always call additional functions after the direct window.open() call... http://jsfiddle.net/vyW3V/6/

Comment: ..or avoid using a popup, then you wouldn't have to try to dodge a popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Please try "_newTab" instead of "_blank"

window.open( URL , "_newtab");

Answer (score -1):

Whether it opens in a new window or a new tab is completely decided by the user, so in short: no, you can't force a new tab to open.

You can use `window.location.replace(...newurl...)` to redirect the user in the same window instead.

Comment: are you sure it's not jsfiddle that is not allowing the redirect?

Comment: yep, jsfiddle blocks this, but it does work. And the reason for window.location.replace is so that the browser doesn't log the previous page in the session, i.e. you don't get stuck in a redirect loop if you click 'back'. It makes more sense as the user didn't explicitly visit the page twice.